# React Native: detect initial app statup with AppState , different from foreground state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react-native app I can use AppState to detect if my app went into background mode or user opened it (foreground mode I think), I was wondering if there is a way to detect initial app start (when app first launches, and the splash screen appears) from a normal foreground state (user opened app and everything is already there).

My code:

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', //can be 'background' or 'active'
        nextAppState => {
        
        setAppState(nextAppState);
       
        if(nextAppState == 'background')
        {
            //entered background mode
        }
        else if(nextAppState == 'active' || null)
        {
            //entered foreground mode
            
        }
    },
    );
    return () => {
      appStateListener?.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The first time your app runs is actually the first time the useEffect is called and you register your listener.

So if you want to set it into state or do anything with it, you can set an initial value for your state which means its in startup.

Like this:

```
const [appState, setAppState] = useState('startup');
```

Later, your listener will update this state to `active` or `background`.